# No output loading PHP page using .ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I'm a recent web development grad with a couple of years of web design experience.  Recently, my (one and only!) client asked for his forms to be re-done.  I've been working a lot with PHP, and I'm trying to implement some validation using jQuery as well as server-side validation.

The validation works nicely.  When I disable javascript, while ugly, it still works.  While finishing things off, I figured that I would add a little loading animation, and then display either a 'success' message, or re-load the form with the error messages.

The animation appears after submission, but a blank page is all that loads.  I'm expecting either an mail success/failure message, or the form again.

See code below.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
<?php @require_once("js/mail.php"); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Mail Testing</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $('form').submit(function(e){       
        e.preventDefault();
        var thisForm = $(this);
        var txt_name = $("#name").val(); 
        var txt_email =  $("#email").val();
        var txt_comments =  $("#comments").val();

        var postData = {
          "name" : txt_name,
          "email" : txt_email,
          "comments" : txt_comments,

        };

        $(this).fadeOut(function(){
            $("#loading").fadeIn(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: thisForm,
                    data: postData,
                    success: function(output) {
                      $("#loading").fadeOut();
                      $("html").html(output);
                    },
                    error: function(output)  {                
                      $("#loading").fadeOut();
                      $("html").html(output);
                    }
               });
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
<style type='text/css'>
body  {
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#wrapper  { padding: 3em; }

.container  {
    display: inline-block; 
    background-color: white; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0, .1) inset, 0 0 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22); 
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.container_inner  {
    padding: .5em 1.3em;    
}

p div, input[type='text'], textarea { text-align: left; width: 100%; padding-right: 1.3em }

p:last-child  {
    text-align: right;  
}

label  { text-align: left; }

.error  {
    color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
    padding-left: .8em;
}

.label, .error  { display: inline;  }

#loading, #success, #error {display: none}

input[type="text"], textarea  {
    padding: .3em .6em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 92%;
    background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0, .4);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, .6);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container_inner">
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" id="Reservations">
            <p>
                <div>
                    <label for="name">Name</label><?php if (isset($field_errors['name'])) { echo $field_errors['name']; } ?>
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php if (isset($name)) { echo $name; } ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <div>
                    <label for="email">Email</label><?php if (isset($field_errors['email'])) { echo $field_errors['email']; }?>
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if (isset($email)) { echo $email; } ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <div>
                    <label for="comments">Comments</label><?php if (isset($field_errors['comments'])) { echo $field_errors['comments']; } ?>
                </div>
                <textarea name="comments" id="comments" value="<?php if (isset($comments)) { echo $comments; }?>"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p>
                <?php echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error); ?>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="submit" />
            </p>
            </form>
            <div id="loading">
                <img src="images/loading.gif" />
            </div>
            <div id="success">
                <h1>Thank you for your request.</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="error">
                <h1>Message could not be sent.</h1>
            </div>
        </div><!-- container_inner -->
    </div><!-- container -->
</div><!-- wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url: thisForm,
```

should be:

```
url: thisForm.attr("action"),
```

You could also simplify the code that gets the field values with:

```
var postData = thisForm.serialize();
```

Comment: Great!  That produced a more expected result.  I've run into a limitation of what I'm doing here though.  The page is being returned, but none of the my server-side validation is running.  Google recatpcha was being inserted via PHP, and it not showing up is what told me this wasn't going to work the way I had hoped.  I really should have known that with what I've learned at school.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("html").html(output);
```

For either success or failure, you are replacing the *entire* content of the page with whatever is returned from the ajax call.

As this is a *self-submitting* form there is no need at all for the ajax call. In the `submit` event remove the following line to allow it to submit as normal:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Alternatively, if you want the animation to happen before the form is submitted, then leave `preventDefault` and use the callback of the `fadeOut` effect to call the `submit` method of the form. You may need a boolean value to prevent this same code being called repeatedly. That is, have a (global) boolean value initially set to `false`; set it to `true` when your `submit` code is first called; if this is `true` then don't prevent the default behaviour (or start the animation).

---

If you want the form submission to happen *asynchronously* - that is, without reloading the form - then you need to:

- Create a separate PHP page/script that will verify the form-input details
- This script returns true or false, or a json object containing error details
- The ajax code handles these returned details, using JavaScript to modify the content of the page (displaying error messages, etc.)
- The `submit` code can start the animation before making the ajax
  request, and stop it when the call is completed (on success or
  failure).

Comment: Isn't that what I want? It's a self-submitting form, so I'd like that to be returned entirely, right?

Comment: The whole purpose of ajax is to not have to reload the page. Typically, the script that processes the request returns a value, or an object, on success, which the current page examines and does something with.

Comment: I usually start with self-submitting forms for this sort of thing.  I never really though of the fact that I'm using .ajax to reload the same page.   Please assume that I'm fetching a separate page then.  Why would this be happening?